# invoice for one customer SQL

Tags: sql

I'm making a query where I want to show an invoice for each costumer. With this query, the total is the amount of all sold products in the given timelaps. How can I make an invoice for just one person?

**My query so far:**

```
use elektrowinkel;

select klanten.Naam, Adres, Product_ID, sum(Prijs) as Totaal
from verkocht_product
inner join klanten
on verkocht_product.Klant_ID = klanten.ID
inner join producten
on producten.ID = verkocht_product.Product_ID

where EXTRACT(month from datum) = 1 and EXTRACT(year from datum) = 2015
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query as it is will error out. you need to use two part name for ambiguous column names.

```
select klanten.Naam, Adres, Product_ID, sum(Prijs) as Totaal
from verkocht_product
inner join klanten   on verkocht_product.Klant_ID = klanten.ID
inner join producten on producten.ID = verkocht_product.Product_ID
GROUP  BY klanten.Naam, Adres, Product_ID
where month(datum) = 1 
and   year(datum) = 2015
```